# Sed on CentOS and FreeBSD

Tags: sed, freebsd

i have the following command

```
sed '/.*href="\(backup[^"]*tbz\)".*/!d;s//\1/;q'
```

which is works on my CentOS install.

But when I try to run it **on FreeBSD** i got the following error:

```
sed: 1: "/.*href="\(backup[ ...": extra characters at the end of d command
(23) Failed writing body
```

What's wrong with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it like this:

```
sed '/.*href="\(backup[^"]*tbz\)".*/\!d;s//\1/;q'
```

Note the extra **\** character escaping your !d command

Answer (score 0):

Apparently FreeBSD `sed` doesn't like the semicolon as command separator.  Try with multiple `-e` options instead:

```
sed -e '/.*href="\(backup[^"]*tbz\)".*/!d' -e 's//\1/' -e q
```

or perhaps newlines:

```
sed '/.*href="\(backup[^"]*tbz\)".*/!d
     s//\1/
     q'
```

(Yes, that's a long single-quoted string with two newlines in it.)